# Swift 3.0+ : Paypal - Braintree integration

Tags: swift, url, paypal, integration, braintree

I am currently integrating Braintree in my iOS app in order to receive payments via PayPal and I exactly followed this guide:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/ios/v4

**My status**: I can receive payments via PayPal, **BUT** only via Safari browser. Instead of opening the PayPal app, Safari is being launched.

Moreover, when i use the default `paypal-ios-sdk` (
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK ),
I can easily pay via the PayPal app and not the browser, but as mentioned here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/

**The paypal mobile sdk´s are deprecated and everybody should migrate to Braintree.**

So, how can I open the PayPal app in my Braintree integration instead of Safari?

Comment: Can you describe the workflow happening and the one you want? I'm assuming right now the user clicks the button. It goes to the Safari App, it opens the "acceptance page" and when they accept it goes back to your app?

Comment: exacty, thats the current flow. But i can not open the paypal app, any idea´s?

Comment: Are you using the Drop-In feature? A bit of code would be useful...

Comment: no i am using a custom inegration, exactly this one: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/checkout-with-paypal/ios/v4